# Using is.na() function to check for missing values in a data frame

Tags: r

The [is.na() function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ursa/versions/3.8.20/topics/is.na) can be used to check if there are any missing values in a data frame. But this just returns a table of boolean (TRUE/FALSE) values, and in a large table, it can be difficult to manually check for any TRUE values. For instance, using the `iris` dataset, I get the following:

```
is.na(iris)

       Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
  [1,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
  [2,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
  [3,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
  [4,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
  [5,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
  [6,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
  [7,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
  [8,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
  [9,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [10,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [11,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [12,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [13,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [14,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [15,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [16,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [17,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [18,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [19,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [20,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [21,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [22,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [23,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [24,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [25,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [26,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [27,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [28,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [29,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [30,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [31,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [32,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [33,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [34,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [35,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [36,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [37,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [38,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [39,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [40,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [41,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [42,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [43,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [44,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [45,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [46,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [47,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [48,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [49,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [50,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [51,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [52,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [53,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [54,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [55,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [56,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [57,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [58,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [59,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [60,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [61,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [62,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [63,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [64,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [65,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [66,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [67,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [68,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [69,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [70,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [71,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [72,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [73,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [74,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [75,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [76,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [77,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [78,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [79,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [80,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [81,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [82,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [83,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [84,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [85,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [86,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [87,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [88,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [89,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [90,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [91,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [92,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [93,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [94,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [95,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [96,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [97,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [98,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
 [99,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[100,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[101,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[102,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[103,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[104,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[105,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[106,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[107,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[108,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[109,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[110,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[111,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[112,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[113,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[114,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[115,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[116,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[117,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[118,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[119,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[120,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[121,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[122,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[123,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[124,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[125,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[126,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[127,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[128,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[129,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[130,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[131,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[132,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[133,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[134,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[135,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[136,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[137,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[138,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[139,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[140,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[141,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[142,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[143,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[144,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[145,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[146,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[147,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[148,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[149,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
[150,]        FALSE       FALSE        FALSE       FALSE   FALSE
```

How can I simplify this so that I don't have to manually check the entire table for TRUE values?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? As you said, `is.na(x)` returns a boolean vector.
You can use `which(is.na(x))` to see which indices of `x` are `NA` or `which(!is.na(x))` to see which indices of `x` are not NA.
You can use `x[!is.na(x)]` to only return non-NA values of `x`

Comment: @Cettt `which(is.na(iris))` outputs `integer(0)`

Comment: What is your expected output? There are no `NA` values in `iris` dataset.

Comment: Ok, I just learned that `integer(0)` is R's way of printing a zero length vector. Now it makes sense.

Comment: Try `any(is.na(x))`

Comment: @AndrewGustar That's another good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use which and any. There is no NA as you see:

```
which(is.na(iris))
integer(0)

and
any(is.na(iris))
[1] FALSE
```